# Jade - set base directory depending on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a jade page, and the first thing I do is set a variable which determines the base directory used by all links.

```
if ! base
  base = '/klog/'
  // base = '/website-clear/klog/'
```

This is actually for a github page, so every time I render the page to html, I have to remember to change the base, and then change it back again for local editing.

There must be a better way of doing it. Currently I am thinking to have an untracked file in the local copy, that includes the base - but is that really necessary?

What is the best way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more robust solution would be checking for environment variables.
Have `NODE_ENV=production` set on the production server, and do not set it on the dev server.

Then in your jade template, render different paths if the environment variable exists.

```
if 'production' == process.env.NODE_ENV
    - base = '/website-clear/klog/'
```

or

```
- base = ( 'production' == process.env.NODE_ENV ? '/website-clear/klog/' : '/klog' );
```

Comment: Probably better to set a variable on the dev machine, and then use... `base = process.env.klog_base_path ? process.env.klog_base_path : "/klog"`

Comment: That could even be simplified to just `base = process.env.klog_base_path || "/klog";` ?